# When I inherit from Thread, does every method in the class run on the new Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, extends, java-threads

I have a program where I want a specific class to run on a `new Thread` every time an instance of it is created. To do this, I am using the `extend Thread` inheritance method of multi-threading. However, what I would like to know is this: When I `extend Thread` for a certain class, will every method of that class which I call (say in the constructor or later on) run on the Thread or will only the ones called in the run() method run on the new Thread?

**Example:**

```
public class Entity extends Thread {
    Entity() {
       super("Bob"); 
       start();
       method2(); //will this run on the new Thread alongside the one called in run()?

    }

    public void run() {
       method1(); //will only this method run on the new Thread? 
    }

    int method1() {
         return 1;
    }

    int method2() {
         return 2;
    }

}
```

**OR:**

```
public class World {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Entity example = new Entity(); 
        example.method2(); //will this run on the new Thread?

    }

}
```

Comment: What did you see when you tried it?

Comment: I couldn't exactly tell, I am gonna try and write a program that has a more obvious output. Cause all the numbers just printed instantly when I added print statements. I am gonna try using Thread.sleep(),

Comment: 1- Don't, you should prefer using a `Runnable` and wrapping it a an instance of a `Thread` and 2- No, or more to the point, not unless the methods are executed from within the context of the `Thread`'s `run` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer okay thanks. Why shouldnt I extend Thread?

Comment: Because you're not creating a new kind of `Thread` (which is what extending would imply). You just have some code you want to run in one.

Comment: @Kayaman ah that makes sense. Okay thanks everyone! That answers my question.

Comment: The fact that the `run` method is in `Thread` doesn't mean it is run on a new thread: it is run on the thread that calls it. e.g. it will be on a new thread if you invoke `thread.start()`, but not if you invoke `thread.run()` directly.

Comment: [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=prefer%20composition%20over%20inheritance) - Basically, you're not adding any new functionality to the `Thread` class, the only method you're interested in is the `run` method.  `Runnable` provides a more flexible solution, as you can just execute the `run` method, pass it to a `Thread` or even pass it through a `ExecutorService`

Comment: @MadProgrammer got you! Makes perfect sense. Apologies for not knowing that, I'd bet you'd be cringing if you went through some of my programs and saw how badly I misuse certain Java classes.

Comment: @AshwinGupta Not as much as I cringe going through my own code some times :P

Comment: What makes you think the methods run on the new thread? And what would that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

**Only** by calling the `start()` method are you creating a new thread. Calling `run()` or any other methods you defined in your class **does not** creates a new thread and **still** runs on the current thread.

Therefore the proper way to use the `Thread` class is to **only** call the constructor and the `start()` method outside of the class. Everything the class is supposed to do should fit in the `run()` method.

---

Let's say you have the following code.

```
public class MyClass extends Thread {
    public void myMethod() {
       //implementation
    }
    public void run() {
       myMethod();
       //other implementation
    }
}
public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       new MyClass().start();
    }
}
```

This code creates a new instance of `MyClass` and calls its `start()` method, which creates a new thread and automatically runs the `run()` method on it.

---

In contrary, consider this code:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       new MyClass().run();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       new MyClass().myMethod();
    }
}
```

Those code only executes the method on the current thread.

---

So to answer your question, the first `method2()` call will not run on seperate thread. `method1()` call will only run on the new thread if `run()` is called through `start()` method.  The second `method2()` call will not run on seperate thread.

---

Also, as mentioned in the other answer, it is never good practice to call `start()` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, all you want to run in another thread must be called in method [run()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()).

Answer (score 0):

Only the method1 call made from the Entity's run method gets called in the new thread created by calling run in Entity's constructor. The call to method2 on the entity from the main method is executed by the main thread. Likewise start is called by the main method, so the call to method2 from the Entity constructor is executed by the main thread.

In your Entity constructor, what happens is that the superclass' start method is called, resulting in a new Thread being created (where the entity object's run method will get called in the new thread), then the current thread proceeds to call method2. Not only does method2 not get called in the new thread, but, depending on how long it takes to get the new thread started, it's likely the run method on Entity could be executed after method2 is invoked (although which happens first is not specified, either thread could execute first).

You can test which thread is running something by logging the thread name. Using `this.getName()` returns the name of the Thread object, not the name of the thread executing the code. You could change Entity's method1 and method2 code to

```
int method1() {
     System.out.println("in method1 of " + this.getName() 
     + ", executed from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     return 1;
}

int method2() {
     System.out.println("in method2 of " + this.getName() 
     + ", executed from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     return 2;
}
```

in order to see the difference between the two, which results in

```
in method2 of Bob, executed from main
in method1 of Bob, executed from Bob
in method2 of Bob, executed from main
```

Be aware that introducing printlns may change the order in which your program's threads execute.

A constructor is for initializing your object; having your thread start before your constructor finishes is error-prone, because the thread is executing the run method before the object has been completely initialized.

Having your Entity extend Thread is awkward for several reasons, you can't subclass from anything else and you risk accidentally overriding methods on Thread. Typically using executors that can use a threadpool is better than having objects try to manage their own dedicated threads. If you specifically want objects that run on their own threads and communicate asynchronously you might check out the [Actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) and specifically [Akka](http://akka.io/).